# Application error on heroku failed to update heroku config

Tags: django, heroku, environment-variables, production-environment

I have hosted a django project on heroku and I'm trying to update my environment variables through heroku config but, I wrote the following command

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY="djang...j*yb13jkqu-+q+l&)#b(g..."
```

And it shows me the following result

```
j*yb13jkqu-+q+l was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try without quotes, just like that:

```
heroku config:set SECRET_KEY=s3cr3Tk3yj*yb13jkqu-+q+l&)#b(g
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#config-var-policies) your env variable **should not include hyphen** characters.